# Creating input command (Not sure what to name it)

Tags: c++, c-strings

I'm not exactly sure of what to call it, since English isn't my native language. What I'm developing is a simple chatter program using winsock2.h for my homework.

What I'm stuck on is making commands. For example, when my user enters '/u username' in the cin stream, I want to be able to change the username of the user to what he sets it as.

Currently, I am sending everything the user types to the server, and let the server determine what to do with the c strings.

So in this case, my server receives '/u username/0'. How do I separate the '/u/0' from the c string, and than detect it?

```
void ServerGame::ProcessTalkLine(char * inStream, unsigned int size, unsigned int id_client)
{
if (size >= 2)  //Any commands would need /'character', which is two character or more
{
    //I have no idea how to do it....
}

else
    sendTalkPackets(inStream, size, id_client);
}
```

Comment: It sounds as though you want to tokenize your input.

Comment: @shuttle87 I've read that strtok tokenizes the c strings, but I have no idea what it really means.

Comment: A tokenizer takes a string and breaks it up into separate parts, we call those tokens. So what you have is a string with the commands and arguments, these are separated by delimiters (in this case spaces). So when you have `/u username` you really want to split this into the tokens `/u` followed by `username`. When you have done that it's much easier to deal with the input as you can just check the first token for the type of command then extract whatever you need from the following token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how many commands you have (or how complex some of them are) the following idea may no be too good ... but for a first start it will work.

```
void ServerGame::ProcessTalkLine(char * inStream, unsigned int size, unsigned int id_client)
{
    if ((inStream == NULL) || (size == 0))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (inStream[0] == '/')   // inStream may contain a command
    {
        if ((size > 3) && (inStream[1] == 'u') && (inStream[2] == ' '))   // inStream contains /u command?
        {
            /* process change of user name */
            printf("changing user name to %s\n", &(inStream[3]));
            return;   // stop here since message is processed!
        }

        /*
        ** strtok blueprint:
        pCommand = strtok(&(instream[1]), " ");    // input string is everything behind the '/'

        if (!strcmp(pCommand, "u"))   // /u username
        {
            username = strtok(NULL, "\0");   // get rest behind pCommand

            // process command

            return;
        }

        if (!strcmp(pCommand, "test"))   // /test arg1 arg2
        {
            arg1 = strtok(NULL, " ");   // get next token
            arg2 = strtok(NULL, "\0");   // get the rest...

            // process command

            return;
        }         
        */
    }

    sendTalkPackets(inStream, size, id_client);
}
```

If you have a lot of commands which are more complicated you may have a look into [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/).

Additionally note that all string functions automatically "remove" (stop processing at) the '\0' character since it terminates the string. Therefore you have to ensure that each string has a '\0' character at the end. Otherwise if you call a string function it will process your entire memory until it finds a '\0'...

Comment: Well I will have a few commands, and am looking to expand upon this in the future. If I were to use strtok, how would I do it? Is there an example you can point me to? The example inside the page is really confusing. Or walk me through the example.

Comment: @user2418426 I've updated my answert with a strtok blueprint. All additional variables need to be of type `char *`. In my blueprint the tokens are sepperated by space(s). Therfore the tokens cannot contain spaces.